# Domain of $\left(f(x)\right)^a$ where $a$ is an irrational number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis

Why, if $f(x)$ is a real function and
$$\left(f(x)\right)^a$$
where $a$ is an irrational number, we put
$$f(x)>0$$
for its domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we write $f(x)^a$ we mean the following expression:
$$f(x)^a=e^{a\ln(f(x))} $$
which requires$f(x)$ to be positive:

---

Otherwise, because if we have $f(x)=-1$ then we will have for example  :
$$(-1)^{1/2},(-1)^{\sqrt2},(-1)^{\pi}$$

they are all of them not defined in $\Bbb R$, and the same goes for negative numbers other then $-1$

Comment: Why $(-1)^{1/2},(-1)^{\sqrt2},(-1)^{\pi}$ are all of them not defined in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: The first term is the square root of $-1$, the square root is only defined for positive numbers ( because in term of comlex numbers $(-1)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}=i$) and the same thing for the others $(-1)^{\pi}=e^{i\pi^2}$ which are not real), in more consise words we can say $(-1)^{1/2}$ is not defined because there is no real number such that $x^2=-1$ and there is no real number such that $e^{x^{-ln(\pi)}}=-1$ because the exponential is always positive.

Comment: I meant $e^{-x\ln(\pi)}$ in the last comment

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. It's ok that $(-1)^{1/2}$ doesn't exists. But $(-1)^{\pi}$, for example? Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: suppose that $(-1)^{\pi}$ is a real number, then $(-1)^{\pi}=a$ ok then we have:$a^{\frac{1}{\pi}}=-1$ hence $e^{\frac{\ln(a)}{\pi}}=-1$ but we know that $e^x$ is always positive so it follows that $-1$ is positive which is acontradiction